# Putting an array into a bigger array

Tags: java

I have an array of terms (terms meaning an object with a coefficient and a degree, represented as for example 1.0x^6). The array that I have right now contains 3 terms:

```
[1.0x^6, 4.0x^5, 10.0x^0].
```

My goal is to create a bigger array with these terms, but ALSO with terms with a 0 coefficient that are not represented in my array. That probably was not too clear, so here is basically what I want my new array to look like:

```
[1.0x^6, 4.0x^5, 0.0x^4, 0.0x^3, 0.0x^2, 0.0x^1, 10.0x^0].
```

Currently, I am iterating through my original array, and if the degree equals the new `array.length - 1`, I am setting `newArray[i] = array[i]`, if that makes sense. For example, for the first term and `i = 0`, the degree is `6`, and so if `6 = newArray.length - 1` (which is 6), then `newArray[i] = array[i]`.

The problem, however is that array is smaller than `newArray`, so I am getting an out of bounds error. Any ideas on how to fix this? Sorry for the long post, thanks!

EDIT: Here is my actual code. Sorry if the explanation was unclear.

```
int max = 0;
    Term temp;

    for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
        max = i;
        for(int j=i; j< array.length; j++) {
            if(array[j].getDegree() > array[max].getDegree()) {
                max = j;
            }

        }
         temp = array[i];
         array[i] = array[max];
         array[max] = temp;
    }
```

Above, the array is sorted in terms of descending degree. I want to now have the new array contain the old terms, but also 0x^i for all the i that are not used in my set of terms.

```
Term[] newArray = new Term[this.degree()+1];
    for (int c = 0; c < newArray.length; c++) {
        if (array[c].getDegree()==newArray.length-1-c) {
            newArray[c] = array[c];
        }
        else {
            newArray[c] = new Term(0, newArray.length-1-c);
        }

    }
```

There are issues in my code above, and I can see that now because in that for loop, array[c] is not defined for any c > 2. Eclipse is telling my that I have an out of bounds error.

Comment: Do not describe your code, [edit] your post and include the actual code.

Comment: Will the degrees in the original array always be in descending order?

Comment: @Sweeper Yes, I sorted the original array and made it to be in descending order in terms of degree.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays have a fixed size. If you want to create a bigger array, you need to know the size beforehand and define it accordingly. Also, it seems that you are going through both the arrays using the same iteration variable.

I assume you are doing something like this:

```
for(i=0;i<newArray.length;i++){
 newArray[i] = array[i]; //size of newArray is bigger than array
}
```

Then you will always get an array index out of bounds exception because "array" is smaller than "newArray" and you go out of bounds when i>=array.length.

You need to fix your code logic.

Comment: I updated my original post to show my actual code. I know the size of the new array, it will be the degree of the highest term in my original array + 1 (represented in my code by this.degree + 1). I'm still having trouble though.

Comment: The problems seems to be this code line :

array[c].getDegree()==newArray.length-1-c

Your "c" which is the iteration variable goes till newArray.length which is greater than the size of "array" yet in the above line of code you are using array[c]. Array index will be out of bounds in your if condition. it seems you are doing exactly what I mentioned in my original answer just inside the "if" condition.

Comment: UPDATE: I reread your comment a bunch of times, and finally something clicked. I changed up the for loop and this part of my code is working now! I do have another question though. If you don't mind reading it, would you prefer me copy and paste my code here, or create a new question? Thanks

Comment: maybe a new question so that other people can see it as well? And if my answer helped you out. Please do upvote :)

Comment: Upvoted. Apparently I'm too new to post another question! Have to wait until tomorrow...